# How to swap multiple cells?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a method to swap/switch data automatically in Excel?

For example:

I have an Excel sheet of almost 16.000 columns. Each column has 5 rows. The 5 rows contain information such as `A,B,C,D,E` but the data is not sorted, so I have the following: `B,A,C,D,E` or `B,C,D,E`.

I want to put all `A`s first and the rows that do not contain an `A` so `(B,C,D,E)` to add a blank row before `B`.

I have only found how to do it manually and with less data and columns.

Comment: Please upload snapshot or upload sample of your workbook ...

Comment: Why the javascript tag? And solutions where you say A,B,C etc do you mean sort alphabetically?

Comment: I cant upload a picture since I am using my phone to adk question.

Comment: I thought I can change it using Javascript. No the A,B,C is just an example. But the things that I need to edit are: BAC, GLO, HDP these are just acronym for certain servicr that the company use. But sometimes i will get the BAC in the second or third row instead of the first row

Comment: So there are only 5 possible values and all columns contain some or all of those values?

Comment: Your data doesn't sound very complicated. Just show a textual representation of some sample data.

Comment: No there are like 20 more rows with other services. It doesnt mather the sequence of the other rows. There are three key services: BAC for basic, BPL for basic plus and PRM for premium. One of the 3 services needs to be in the first column. Because people with BAC cannot have BPL or PRM at the same time so they are unique. But I find then in the second or third even in the 20th row but they need to be in the first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a formula (fill down and then across):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, this below code should work for the 3 items you listed. If you have more options, just update the fields in the arrays

```
Sub CFixer()
Dim c As Long, WS As Worksheet, i As Integer, startRow As Integer, lastRow As Long, checkRNG As Range

Dim Check(2) As String 'must match below list
Check(0) = "BAC"
Check(1) = "GLO"
Check(2) = "HDP"

Dim T(2) As String ' must match list above
startRow = 1 'first row to evaluate


Set WS = ActiveSheet
lastRow = startRow + UBound(Check) 'last row to look to replace

For c = 1 To WS.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Set checkRNG = Range(WS.Cells(startRow, c), WS.Cells(lastRow, c))

    For i = 0 To UBound(Check)

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(checkRNG, Check(i)) > 0 Then
            T(i) = Check(i)
        Else
            T(i) = ""
        End If

    Next i

    checkRNG.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(T)

Next c

End Sub
```

This will change rows as shown:

[image: Before Picture]

CORRECTED After Picture:
[image]